# Can I use the lens from Canon AE-1 on a Canon EOS DSLR, with an adaptor maybe?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I have a Canon AE-1 (film) and I bought a digital slr camera Canon EOS 60D. I have lenses from the AE-1 camera, but I don't know if there are some adaptors to use so they fit in the 60D camera... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The Canon AE-1 was an FD Mount camera, where as the Canon 60D and all Canon cameras since 1987 or so use either EF or EF-S(or both) lens mounts.

What that means, is that it is possible to use your old lenses with an adapter as you guessed. Unfortunately, the adapters don't make actual use all that fun. They usually have issues with focusing at a distance, and actual optical quality. This is for the straight up adapter without any glass to correct.

The other option is to get an adapter that has glass in it, which can fix the infinity focus issues, but will also put a big dent in your pocket. These still aren't perfect, but are more manageable.  If you are looking to get the same quality out of an old FD lens, compared to a new "L" class lens, by using the adapter, you are going to be sad unfortunately.

If you have some old lenses already, the adapters aren't all that expensive, under $50USD typically, so it may be worth investing in and seeing how you like it.