# Which mount adaptor do I need to mount an old Tokina FL/FD lens on a Canon 30D?

Tags: canon, old-lenses, lens-mount, tokina, lens-adapter

I have an old Tokina Fully Automatic Lens 400mm F-6.3 lens.

Says on a small label: "To fit C/FD Canon FL and FD lens series"

I have a Canon 30D.

Which is the right mount adaptor to use? Best if you can provide the exact name as I will Google it. Much thanks!

Comment: You would need an adapter from Canon FD to Canon EF mount, but there are serious limitations to consider. See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18102/can-i-use-the-lens-from-canon-ae-1-on-a-canon-eos-60d-with-an-adaptor-maybe

Answer (score 3):

Canon FL/FD mount lenses are not good choices for adapting to Canon EF-mount bodies (e.g. 30D, and any other EOS camera).

There are FD-EF adapters on eBay, but to be able to focus to infinity, you would need adapter with corrective optics because of negative difference in focal flange depth between these two mounts. Unfortunately, corrective optics degrade picture quality significantly, even when using original Canon FD-EF adapter (expensive and very difficult to find). With adapters without corrective optics, lenses cannot be focused to infinity.
Specifically, with lens this long, you could focus close to infinity even with non-corrected adapter (without lens element), so if you can score one adapter for cheap, it's possibly worth the hassle.

Basically, avoid FL/FD lenses if you're using Canon EOS camera - they are not a good match.
If you already have one, get an adapter off the eBay - adapters without glass are macro-only, adapters with glass degrade picture quality.

Comment: Thx elkarrde. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. The cons outweigh the pros it seems. I will research more on the adapter you've mentioned.